Estimating bias of a coin with an unknown bias $p \in [0,1]$, approximately normally distributed
I posted this on MSE, but someone suggested to post it here instead. Suppose you are given a coin that is biased towards heads with probability $p$. You do not know $p$, but you know that $p$ is drawn from some truncated normal distribution in $[0,1]$ centered at $1/2$. Given $N$ flips, what can you say about $p$ and with how much confidence?
As my question is vague, I'm not looking for a specific answer but a way to attack the problem. I am somewhat familiar with the case when $p$ is drawn uniformly from $[0,1]$, but I'm not sure how to adapt the reasoning to this case.

FWIW the math would be very much nicer if you were willing to assume a Beta distribution rather than a truncated normal ...

I’m not sure what to make of the idea that we know the coin is biased yet also assume $p$ has an expected value of $1/2$.

Also, this is why Bayesians use simulation. There is a nice calculation if you assume a beta distribution that is a conjugate prior, but for a truncated normal, I very much do not envy you calculating the posterior.

@Dave, maybe the OP is trying to express that the prior distribution is a (0,1) truncated Normal with mean 1/2?

@BenBolker I absolutely suspect the same, but that phrasing did strike me as strange and warranting elaboration by the OP.

@Ben I'd have interpreted it just that way, except that the OP clearly says "biased toward heads" which doesn't fit that at all.

You may benefit from reading the Exercise in David MacKay's book (p. 59) which starts with "When spun on edge 250 times, a Belgian one-euro coin came up heads 140 times and tails 110. ‘It looks very suspicious to me’, said ..."

Is this what you're after? https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/389347/102399

I'll proceed on the assumption that the stated centered-at-$\frac12$ truncated normal is intended and the "biased toward heads" part is not.
Your question is Bayesian in form; you're specifying a prior.
I'm going to move to talking about $\theta$ and $n$ rather than $p$ and $N$ for reasons of convention (and to avoid a notation clash in what I do). We can always change back at the end if need be.
Let's start with some generic prior $p(θ)$ on $(0,1)$ (given your mentioned prior doesn't put any atoms of probability at the boundary this will be equivalent).
Let $X\sim \operatorname{Bin}(n,θ)$.
From Bayes theorem
$p(θ|X=x) \propto p(x|θ)\, p(θ)\quad$ (hence $\propto θ^x (1-θ)^{n-x}\, p(θ)$)
Generally speaking for arbitrary priors $p(θ)$  this posterior density won't be readily integrable (which you will need to be able to rescale it to make it integrate to 1), but it can be done numerically.
In your case
since $x$ and $n$ are integer and the prior  is truncated normal:
$p(θ)=\frac {\frac{1}{\sigma}\varphi ({\frac {2θ-1}{2\sigma }})}{2\Phi ({\frac {1}{2\sigma }})-1}$ for $\sigma>0$ and $0<θ<1$,
it can be done algebraically - the likelihood is a polynomial and recursive formulas for moments of truncated normals are obtainable, but unless $n$ is small it's decidedly unwieldy. e.g. if $n=2$ and $x=1$, sure, you can write this down.
Having an algebraic expression for the posterior is probably not what you're after though. If you just want to draw the posterior or calculate its mean and standard deviation (say), you don't need an algebraic expression for that, the normalizing factor is readily computed numerically.

The blue line segment below the densities (at 2/3) marks the sample proportion, where the likelihood is at a maximum. We see the posterior has moved toward that from the prior, and is narrower than the prior, since it incorporates the sample information.
That mode of the posterior is roughly around 0.637. (A little code added at the end to outline the simplicity of the calculation)
If the choice of truncated normal was fairly arbitrary and you just wanted something vaguely of that shape, you could consider taking a mixture of beta distributions as the prior to get about the shape you want, resulting in a mixture of betas in the posterior but whether this is worth it depends on what you're doing and what resources are available. If a single beta or even a mixture of two is adequate, the posterior is easy to work with. In the case of my example, the above grey prior is visually quite well approximated by a two component mixture of betas and the resulting posterior is pretty similar to the 'exact' one in dark red above (which also acts as a check; it suggests that if I did make any errors in the calculation, they didn't have much impact on the output).
For binomial proportions if you're attempting to define/elicit a prior, besides playing with beta distributions, a piecewise linear
(or even piecewise polynomial) approximation may sometimes be convenient. This results in a piecewise polynomial posterior for which moments might be fairly readily computed if working by hand.

    # define prior and unnorm. posterior, integrate posterior over (0,1)
    prior = function(t,sigma=.3) dnorm(t,.5,sigma)/(2*pnorm(1,.5,sigma)-1)
    postUn = function(t,x=8,n=12) t^x*(1-t)^(n-x)*prior(t)
    area = integrate(postUn,0,1)$value
    
    curve(postUn(x)/area,ylim=c(0,3.5),col="darkred",xlab="p",ylab="density")
    curve(prior,col=8,add=TRUE)
    abline(h=0,v=c(0,1),lty=3,col=8)
    rug(8/12,col=4)




As an alternative approximation (for the fun, because it is not faster).
To obtain a solution in terms of a sum of beta distributions*, you can

convert the normal distribution into a Taylor series expansion
convert that to an expansion of beta distributions.
solve for the individual beta distributions (whose posteriors will be again beta distributions) .


A Taylor series representation of the exponential is
$$e^y = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{y^k}{k!}$$
substituting $y=\theta(1-\theta)/a$, we can write
$$e^{\frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{a}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\theta^k(1-\theta)^k}{a^kk!}$$
and the term from the truncated normal distribution is similar
$$e^{\frac{ -(\theta-0.5)^2}{2\sigma^2} }  = e^{ \frac{\theta(1-\theta)-0.25}{2\sigma^2} } = b e^{ \frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{a} }$$
with $a = 2\sigma^2$ and $b=e^{ \frac{-0.25}{2\sigma^2} } $
So we have the prior
$$ \frac{1}{1-2\Phi(-0.5/\sigma)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi\sigma^2} }e^{\frac{(\theta-0.5)}{2\sigma^2}} = \frac{1}{1-2\Phi(-0.5/\sigma)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi\sigma^2} } e^{ \frac{-0.25}{2\sigma^2} } \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\theta^k(1-\theta)^k}{(2\sigma^2)^kk!}$$
Where $\Phi$ is the CDF of the normal distribution and used in the normalisation term of the truncated normal distribution.
In terms of beta distributions $f_{\alpha,\beta}(\theta)$ the prior is
$$f(\theta) = \frac{e^{ -1/(8\sigma^2) } }{(1-2\Phi(-0.5/\sigma))\sqrt{2 \pi\sigma^2}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{B(k+1,k+1)}{(2\sigma^2)^kk!}f_{k+1,k+1}(\theta)$$
and after observing $h$ heads and $t$ tails the posterior is
$$f(\theta) = \frac{e^{ -1/(8\sigma^2) } }{(1-2\Phi(-0.5/\sigma))\sqrt{2 \pi\sigma^2}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{B(k+1,k+1)}{(2\sigma^2)^kk!}f_{k+1+h,k+1+t}(\theta)$$

Let's put this to a test with the same values from Glen_B's post. $\sigma = 0.3$, $h=8$, $t=4$.

### parameters of the problem
sigma = 0.3
heads = 8
tails = 4

### parameters of the computation 
n = 20   ### number of twrms in the series
k = 0:n
theta = seq(0,1,0.01)

### compute the beta distribution 
### the sapply function will give a matrix as output 
### with values for different theta
### and for different alpha=beta=x+1
betas_prior = sapply(k, FUN = function(x) { 
  dbeta(theta,x+1,x+1)
})

betas_posterior = sapply(k, FUN = function(x) { 
  ### for the posterior the beta distributions 
  ### change very simple by adding
  ### heads and tails to alpha and beta
  dbeta(theta,x+1+heads,x+1+tails)
})

### the factors used in the summation
commonfactor = exp(-1/8/sigma^2)/(1-2*pnorm(-0.5/sigma))/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2)
factor = beta(k+1,k+1)/(2*sigma^2)^k/factorial(k)

### compute prior and posterior
### this %*% operator is a matrix multiplication
prior =     commonfactor * betas_prior %*% factor
posterior = commonfactor * betas_posterior %*% factor


plot(theta,prior, type = "l", ylim = c(0,max(posterior)), 
     xlab = expression(theta), ylab = "density")
lines(theta,posterior, col =4)

text(0.2,1, "prior", pos = 2)
text(0.55,3, "posterior", col = 4, pos = 2)


* The reason for trying to convert to a beta distribution is because it is a conjugate prior with very simple updating rules.

Aside from being less fast, this method is also less general. The series expansion is easily done for a truncated normal distribution that is centered at $\theta = 0.5$, such thatbit is symmetrical. But for other cases it will become more problematic.

The beta function and division by the factorial might probably be simplified. But it doesn't make the principle easier to follow (which is a bad excuse for me being to lazy to figure it out; Those beta and gamma functions are always a bit annoying with either a +1 or -1).

My rough visual  approximation of the $\sigma=0.3$ truncated normal prior was 40% beta(1,1) and 60% beta(2.7,2.7) - it was a trivial matter to approximate the weight of the first component (it would be about the y-intercept of the original prior, which I did by eye), so the only thing left to do was guess the "2.7" on the second one -- which value was my second guess. The curves were nearly coincident. That was sufficient for my purposes, just showing that it was plausible. If I was trying to work with just a calculator and needed a posterior mean, say, something like this might be worth doing

Another alternative is to approximate the multiplication of the likelihood (which has the form of a beta distribution) and the prior (which has the form of a normal distribution) as a product of two normal distributions instead
(the normal distribution is a conjugate distribution for the normal distribution and allows easy computations, it remains the same when the distribution is truncated).
The likelihood function for $x$ heads out of $n$ trials is
$$\theta|x \propto \theta^x(1-\theta)^{n-x}$$
this is the shape of a beta $x+1,n-x+1$ distribution with mean $$\mu' = \frac{x+1}{n+2}$$ and variance $$\sigma'^2 = \frac{(x+1)(n-x+1)}{(n+2)^2(n+3)}$$
the approximated product of the prior and the likelihood is then
$$\begin{array}{}
\theta|X &\propto& \exp\left(- \frac{(\theta-\mu')^2}{\sigma'^2} - \frac{(\theta-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \\
&\propto& \exp\left(- \frac{\theta-\mu^\star}{2{\sigma^\star}^2} \right)
 \end{array}$$
with $$\begin{array}{}
\mu^\star& = &\frac{\left(\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2} + \frac{\mu'}{\sigma'^2}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2} + \frac{1}{\sigma'^2}\right)}\\
{\sigma^\star}^2 &= & \left( \frac{1}{\sigma^{2}} +\frac{1}{\sigma'^2} \right)^{-1}
\end{array}$$

Let's put this to a test with the same values from Glen_B's post. $\sigma = 0.3$, $h=8$, $t=4$. And plot it allong the result from the other answer.

For larger sample sizes the approximation works better.

Above, the normal approximation has been based on matching the mean and variance of the beta distribution/likelihood that is to be approximated. Possibly different methods to approximate the beta distribution might improve the result a bit.
### parameters of the problem
sigma = 0.3
mu = 0.5
heads = 8
tails = 4
theta = seq(0,1,0.01)

### prior
f = pnorm(1,mu,sigma)-pnorm(0,mu,sigma)
prior = dnorm(theta,mu,sigma)/f

### compute all those sigma and mu
alpha = heads+1
beta = tails+1
mu_prime = alpha/(alpha+beta)
sigma_prime = sqrt(alpha*beta/(alpha+beta)^2/(alpha+beta+1))

sigma_star = 1/sqrt(1/sigma^2+1/sigma_prime^2)
mu_star = (mu/sigma^2 + mu_prime/sigma_prime^2)*sigma_star^2

### posterior
f_star = pnorm(1,mu_star,sigma_star)-pnorm(0,mu_star,sigma_star)
posterior = dnorm(theta,mu_star,sigma_star)/f_star

### add to plot from the other answer
lines(theta,prior)
lines(theta,posterior, col =4)



I believe that this is a fun approach. I guess that for most people, the first impression to attack the problem (except for glenB's straightforward approach of multiplying the two things and work out the normalisation constant computationally) is to try to work with the prior. Trying to approximate that prior with something that allows an easy computation with conjugate distributions. But one can just as well try to work with the likelihood instead.

Related: What is the role, if any, of the Central Limit Theorem in Bayesian Inference?
